# MYSQL Multiple Select For Same Category?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 tables (scenes, categories, scenes_categories ) in a many to many relationship.

scenes ( id, title, description )
categories ( id, title )
scenes_categories ( scene_id, category_id )

I'm having problems making a query to select scenes that must match multiple categories. For example, I might want to select scenes that match category 3 AND category 5 AND category 8, but I can't figure out how to get this to work.

So far I've got something like

```
SELECT scenes.id, scenes.title, scenes.description
FROM scenes
LEFT JOIN scenes_categories ON scenes.id = scenes_categories.scene_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON scenes_categories.category_id = categories.id
WHERE scenes_categories.category_id = '3'
AND scenes_categories.category_id = '5'
AND scenes_categories.category_id = '8'
AND scenes.id = '1'
```

How can I select for records that must match all the category ID's specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to require that a row exists in your many-to-many table for that sceneId, for each categoryId you are requiring:
So try this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.title, s.description
FROM scenes s
WHERE s.id = '1'
   And Exists (Select * From scenes_categories 
               Where scene_id = s.Id
                  And category_id = '3')
   And Exists (Select * From scenes_categories 
               Where scene_id = s.Id
                  And category_id = '5')

   And Exists (Select * From scenes_categories 
               Where scene_id = s.Id
                  And category_id = '8')
```

another option that should work is to do three inner joins instead:

```
SELECT s.id, s.title, s.description
FROM scenes s
  Join scenes_categories c3 
      On c3.scene_id  = s.Id
           And c3.category_id ='3'
  Join scenes_categories c5 
      On c5.scene_id  = s.Id
           And c5.category_id ='5'
  Join scenes_categories c8 
      On c8.scene_id  = s.Id
           And c8.category_id ='8'     
WHERE s.id = '1'
```

Comment: Pretty sure he was looking for a dynamic solution here.

Comment: Sorry, I took off my downvote... didn't realize he didn't want an OR relationship

Comment: Thank you so much! I implemented the second solution you suggested and it worked like a charm; albeit it took me some time to figure out exactly how it works conceptually, haha.

Answer (score 3):

Charles Bretana's answer will work, but might want to check the performance of that against this to see which works better for you.

```
SELECT * FROM scenes
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT scene_id
  FROM scenes_categories
  WHERE category_id IN (3,5,8)
  GROUP BY scene_id
  HAVING count(*) = 3
) valid ON scenes.id = valid.scene_id
```

Assuming your SQL is dynamic, this will probably be a bit easier to implement.